# What does "respective constituents" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "their disbled staff" or "their disable customers"?

"We are big on giving back to **our respective constituents**. We do that by giving back monetarily to organizations like Wounded Warriors," he said."And also by training and mentoring disabled veterans."

Source: https://www.businessinsider.com.au/mischler-financials-role-on-snap-ipo-2017-2

Comment: Your link is broken, maybe you have not copied the entire url.

Comment: This is a little ambiguous because "constituents could refer to either the components their made of (implying their own staff), or the people they serve (implying their customers).  Given the context that they are giving money to external support organizations and training/mentoring apparently external veterans, rather than providing in-house benefits, it suggests that they are referring to  their customers and possibly other disabled members of the community who are the pool of potential customers.